# How to create a property of type System.Windows.Media.Color with a custom value

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, system.windows.media

I'm creating a ViewModel and I can't find a way to create something like the following pseudo code:

```
 private Color _GradientColor = new Color().DodgerBlue;  //Something like this
```

I can do:

```
private SolidColorBrush _GradientColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue);
```

But it is not what i need.

Comment: I don't understand. [Colors.DodgerBlue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors.dodgerblue) is a `System.Windows.Media.Color` so you should be able to do `private Color _GradientColor = Colors.DodgerBlue;`. Also, where's the custom value you mentioned in the title?

Comment: I don't know how to create a custom value such as #FF007EEE for example. I would like some sample

Comment: There's [Color.FromRgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb) or one of the other From methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two are not remotely equivalent.

```
private Color _GradientColor;
_GradientColor = new Color().DodgerBlue;  //Something like this
```

You are creating a instance of Color, to then access a property that contains a instance for DodgerBlue?

```
private SolidColorBrush _GradientColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue);
```

Here you create a instance of SolidColorBrush, giving it a Constant, Static, or Enumeration value as input. As it is Colors (plural) it is extremely likely a Enumeration - a thing you can not instantiate. If it is a Enumeration, this might be the code you are looking for:

```
private Color _GradientColor;
_GradientColor = Colors.DodgerBlue;
```

However, that might be the wrong track overall. As a general, the ViewModel does **not** deal with Colors. That is a unambigious, View side thing. You may be looking for a converter? Or maybe you have a special ViewModel just for stuff like Colors?